# Page-level locking in Jet 4.0 insert? "Can't update; currently locked" error

Tags: ms-access, locking, jet

I'm getting this error intermittently before record insert on a subform.

The subform is in 'continuous records' mode. The subform recordsource is a parameter query opened via querydef.OpenRecordset, in dbOpenDynaset mode.

Using MS Access 2003, Access 2000 file format for front-end and back-end, both FE and BE have record-level locking selected, all forms have "No Locks" for RecordLocks.

Googling, it seems many people have had similar situations but no solutions found.

Any ideas?  It seems like page-level locking is being used instead of record-level, when the insert is done on the form.

1. Could it be that the back-end connection (via DAO OpenDatabase) reverts to page-level locking?  Any setting in the DAO connectionstring that could be helpful if so?
2. Could it be that by opening the recordset via querydef, it uses page-level locking, so that a simultaneous record-update and record-insert (recordset.AddNew or whatever) may conflict?  Microsoft's article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189633%28v=office.10%29.aspx) suggests this might be the case (although it's unclear, as OpenRecordset is supposed to be OK):

> However, any SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) queries — that is, queries that add, delete, or modify records — that are run from ADO (when you use the Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider), DAO, or the Access query user interface will use page-level locking. Page-level locking is used for SQL DML statements to improve performance when you are working with many records. However, even when record-level locking is turned on, it is not used for updates to values in memo fields and values in fields that are indexed — they still require page-level locking.

Comment: I have always worked on the basis of the assertion that DAO uses page-level locking and cannot use record-level locking. Personally, I don't think record-level locking is that big of a deal. Optimistic locking vastly decreases any collisions of edits between users. You seem to be updating a table that you have open in a subform. Is it possible the form is dirty when you attempt the update?

Comment: The outer form isn't bound to any recordset, so the fact that it's a subform is not actually that relevant. The situation where it's happening, I think, is that one user is editing an existing record and another user is attempting enter a new record - it's at the point where the second starts typing in the new record (and it runs the AddRec or whatever). I will try explicitly setting optimistic locking in the OpenRecordset but don't expect this to help since the users are editing different records.  I may try instead disabling AllowAdds form property and do it manually with an insert query.

Comment: If the problem is being caused by two actual users, and not by yourself locking the pages with unsaved edits, doing the insert in SQL won't change anything at all. If it's locked, it's locked. I think there's something else going on here, as I've never encountered a page locking issue in production use when under optimistic locking.

Comment: Oh that's funny.. I've been pulled out of bed at 4am to come and work on a manufacturing line.. because jet just isn't reliable enough for single-user.           re: I've never encountered a page locking issue in production use when under optimistic locking.

Comment: Maybe the problem with your apps, Aaron, is not Jet, but the capability of the developer using Jet.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think the source of my problem is, and perhaps why Aaron said that Jet "randomly locks records". From the DAO docs:

> [Recordset.AddNew Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220954%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
>
> **Note** When you use **AddNew** in a Microsoft Jet workspace and the database engine has to create a new page to hold the current record, page locking is pessimistic. If the new record fits in an existing page, page locking is optimistic.

I think I am seeing it more in this project because it involves frequently *inserting a large number of records* when a user opens a form, therefore the db engine is creating a lot of new pages, therefore AddNew - as called during the Insert event on the form - has more likelihood to revert to pessimistic locking, therefore more chance for collisions with other records being edited concurrently on the same page.

I will set up a testbed to see if my suspicions are true.

If so, it seems like you could avoid it by *not* using `AddNew` (`AllowAdditions = False`), and *instead* insert new records via a query + refresh the form recordset. Even if the insert query forces a new page, with `querydef.Execute` you aren't opening a recordset, so theoretically there should be no locking issue.

Comment: Well I managed to reproduce the error in a test environment (running an insert query every n seconds while in a separate process doing AddNew + Update every m seconds). And I don't get the error doing it the querydef.Execute vs AddNew way. That's the good news. But I did get various other concurrency related errors, somewhat frequently.

Comment: So I will need to evaluate a different backend as well as other options besides Access. In the short term I'm going to change the interface to avoid AddNew, and put in place an error handler that retries execute() and openrecordset() when concurrency errors are tripped.

If anyone wants to see my testbed code, let me know.